# Js rotate from input

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, return

I want to rotate a div from input so when I change the number to 20 for example, it'll rotate my div with 20deg

`.style.transform = “rotate(“n” + “deg”` did not work for me

```js
function fs(n) {
  n = document.querySelector('input').value;
  document.getElementById('bb').style.transform = "rotate(".push(n)")";
  console.log(n + "deg");
}
```

```html
<input type='number' placeholder='ttt' oninput='fs()'>
<div class='bb' id='bb'></div>
<button onclick='fs()'>Click</button>
```

Comment: `"rotate("+n+"deg)"` ...?

Comment: Please use better variable and placeholder names too

Comment: Works now, can t believe, thank you but i don t really understand why it works and why +”deg)”

Comment: It works because that's the syntax. E.g. if you'd want to rotate it 45° then the style rule would be transform: rotate(45deg);
So what this code is doing is setting the tranform style rule to rotate(ndeg). "rotate(" is a string and "deg)" is a string, n is your variable. The plusses are there to concatenate it into one string. A different approach would be \`rotate(${n}deg)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few issues.

It helps to make the div position absolute and then create the actual css statement

You want `rotate(ndeg)` so you need to create `ndeg` correctly. That is EITHER concatenation `"rotate("+n+"deg)"` OR template literals

```
`rotate(${n}deg)`
```

```js
function fs(n) {
  n = document.querySelector('input').value;
  document.getElementById('bb').style.transform = `rotate(${n}deg)`;
}
```

```css
#bb { position:absolute }
```

```html
<input type='number' placeholder='Rotation in deg' oninput='fs()'>
<div class='bb' id='bb'>MY DIV</div>
```